# Gupta Centura Team Developer

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

We have applications to migrate from gupta 3.1 to 6.3, and after using migration wizard, quick tabs did not work since it showed only the first tab.

How to fix it or how to use the old quick tab?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The old quick tab works with TD 6.3 an higher. As far as I know we did not use the migration wizard. We just opened the old sourcefiles with the new TD.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently migrating from 4.1 to 7.4 and the quickTabs are working very well. I know that there were some improvements with the Tab Controls in 7.x Versions, maybe it's an option to Update to an higher Version than 6.x?

Anyways have you tried converting with the "ConvertTD.exe"? We've seen much better results with the Converter than converting with cbX.X.exe

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you are migrating to TeamDeveloper 6.3 - which is now many years beyond end-of-life according to OpenText. The latest version is v7.5, either 32 or 64 bit, and far out-performs v6.3 .

So the usual migration path from an ANSI version as old as v3.1, requires a fair bit of manual intervention, as the migration wizard was never intended to cope with such a  big jump, especially from an ANSI version (3.1) to a UNICODE version ( 6.3 ).

Its waaaay safer and easier in the long run to migrate manually by simply opening each file in the TD6.3 outline - then it will convert automatically. Go here to get the full migration logistics: [Porting older TD versions to a newer version](https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/Porting)

However, it is well documented that the 'TabBar' object which was introduced in TD5.1 is the modern replacement of the old QuickTabs, and is quicker and easier to implement - with a few tweaks.
Go here to see more about the TabBar object ( which you should be now using ) :
[TabBar instead of Quick Tabs](https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php?title=Tabbar)